# using the Milne Thomson theorem to calculate complex potential

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem, as I'm unsure on how to begin.  The problem is the following.

Two equal line sources of strength $k$ are located at $x=3a$ and $x=-3a$, near a circular cylinder of radius $a$ with axis normal to the $x-y$ plane and passing through the origin. The fluid is incompressible and the flow is irrotational and inviscid. I need to use the Milne-Thomson circle theorem to show that the complex potential for this flow is 
$$ w(z) = k\ln\left(a^{4}-9a^{2}z^{2}-9\frac{a^{6}}{z^{2}}+81a^{4}\right). $$
I know that a line source of strength $k$ has a complex potential $w(z)=k\ln(z)$. I just don't understand how to apply this with the theorem to get the required result.

Here is a link to the theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne-Thomson_circle_theorem

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_1(z) = k\ln(z-3a)$ and $f_2(z)$ be the complex potential for the line source at $x=3a$ and $x=-3a$ respectively (without the cylinder). The complex potential $f(z)$ for these double line sources (without the cylinder) is just the sum of the individual complex potential, i.e. 
$$ f(z) = f_1(z) + f_2(z) = k\ln\left(z^2 - 9a^2\right). $$
By virtue of the Milne-Thomson Circle theorem, we just need to compute $\overline{f\left(\dfrac{a^2}{\bar z}\right)}$: 
\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{a^2}{\bar z}\right) & = k\ln\left(\frac{a^4}{\bar z^2} - 9a^2\right) \\
\overline{f\left(\frac{a^2}{\bar z}\right)} & = k\ln\left(\frac{a^4}{z^2} - 9a^2\right).
\end{align*}
The desired expression for $w(z)$ follows by adding $f(z)$ and $\overline{f\left(\dfrac{a^2}{\bar z}\right)}$ together and I will leave this computation for you.

Comment: Brilliant, it looks so simple now, I think the main problem i had was calculating the $f(z)$ i didnt realise that i could just add and subtract the $x$ coordinates into the complex potentials for a line source, Thank you very much!. , how would i go about finding the flow speed? would i just differentiate $w(z)$ ?

Comment: @Gibberish That could be daunting! You are almost correct, the flow speed is given by $\left|\dfrac{dw}{dz}\right|$.

Comment: Would you recommend directly differentiating $w(z)$ or would it be best to re write the $z$ terms in terms of $Re^i\theta$?& would that be the speed at the surface of the cylinder ? i assume so

Comment: @Gibberish This is tricky. I would just directly differentiate $w(z)$ to be honest, but with the expression before we apply product rule for the logarithm, i.e. using $w(z) = f(z) + \overline{f(a^2/\bar z)}$ and differentiating these two separately. If it turns out to be a real mess, then using $z=Re^{i\theta}$ is probably better.

Comment: it simplifies nicely, thanks!&
would you mind having a quick look at this problem, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699109/fluid-dynamics-calculating-the-maximum-possible-speed-and-finding-the-pressure?noredirect=1#comment5577186_2699109

Comment: how would I go about determining the position of points on the surface of the cylinder at which the pressure is minimum ?